# How to correctly type a mapOptional function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-types, conditional-types

I have the following function which takes an optional value and maps it to a different value unless it is `null` or `undefined`. My current solution to this looks as follows:

```
type Return<I, R> = I extends null ? null
                  : I extends undefined ? undefined
                  : R;

/**
 * Maps an optional value to another optional by a callback.
 *
 * @param input - The input value to map.
 * @param callback - The callback to map the value.
 * @returns An optional mapped value.
 */
export function mapOptional<I, R>(input: I, callback: (value: NonNullable<I>) => R): Return<I, R> {
  if (input === null) {
    return null as Return<I, R>;
  }

  if (typeof input === 'undefined') {
    return undefined as Return<I, R>;
  }

  return callback(input!) as Return<I, R>;
}
```

There are two things which bug me:

- Why do I have to cast the return values to `Return<I, R>`?
- Why do I have to use the bang operator `!` so input becomes `NonNullable`?

An improvement to my solution would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now conditional types have a strange relation with the return types of the function, but in your case you can do a little trick with having an overload that has the widest type possible and also handle edge cases around known `null` and `undefined` being passed to the function:

```
function mapOptional<I = any, R = unknown>(input: null, callback: (value: I) => R): null
function mapOptional<I = any, R = unknown>(input: undefined, callback: (value: I) => R): undefined
function mapOptional<I, R>(input: I, callback: (value: NonNullable<I>) => R)
    : I extends (undefined | null) ? I : R
function mapOptional<I, R>(input: I, callback: (value: I) => R) {
    if (input === null) {
        return null;
    }

    if (input === undefined) {
        return undefined;
    }


    return callback(input);
}

mapOptional(undefined, x => x.toFixed()) // type is undefined
mapOptional(null, x => x + 5) // type is null
mapOptional(56, x => x + 5).toFixed() // works

declare const optionalNumber: number | undefined

const r = mapOptional(optionalNumber, x => x + 5) // undefined | number
if (r) {
    console.log(r.toFixed())
}
```

Comment: Thanks Grassator! This actually works in my case. I thought it was simply because the TypeScript type system can't handle it yet. Thank you very much for your code!